# Radio buttons in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, report, radio-button

How do I add radio buttons as my parameter type in SSRS reports?

Thanks in advance,
Anna

Answer (score 9):

It can be done, but only for a boolean parameter - i.e. you can only have True/False, not a custom list of radio options.

Add a parameter to your report of type 'Boolean'.  'Available Values' should be set to 'Non-queried' - but make sure to leave the grid of values completely blank.

In the 'Default Values' section, again choose Non-Queried - but in the expression box type 'True' or 'False' (i.e. dependant upon your desired default value).

The parameter should now render as a radio button - with the option of True/False.

Note, this is all with the Report Designer in BIDS - I haven't tried it via the Report Builder click-once app.

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to the Reporting Services web interface, you can't. Selectable value lists appear as  dropdown lists. You can configure to the ability to select multiple values, which are rendered as a dropdown list of checkboxes.

Comment: You can have the data type of the parameter as 'Boolean' which will render your parameter as radio button

Answer (score 5):

First pass a bool value to your parameter, and then use that parameter field instead of m_dhkDentalStatusGood in the following expression:

```
=iif( Fields!m_chkDentalStatusGood.Value , Chr(158), Chr(153))
```

And change the font for that texbox to "Wingdings 2".

NOTE: This should also appear when you export your report as PDF.

Comment: It doesn't support print preview and print.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that they don't have them - at least they are not documented in the BOL help.  It is equivalent in function to the list where you can only select one item.

Comment: You can have the data type of the parameter as 'Boolean' which will render your parameter as radio button

Comment: Not exactly a radio button in the classic sense, where you can define your choice.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicions are confirmed:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2414397&SiteID=1

These msdn forums are a good resource.  Most questions have already been asked ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add radio buttons to the report parameter in SSRS... Multi valued parameter gets check boxes automatically, if the parameter is single select, all default values appear in drop down, its behaviour is similar to the behaviour of radio button..

Answer (score 1):

Not true, I am actually having a problem with 2 reports using the same parameter but displaying it differently. The parameter is boolean, and in one report it renders as a dropdown list and in the other it renders as a radio button list. Therefore, both are possible, the question is why is the same code being rendered differently by two different reports?
    
      Boolean
      
        
          True
        
      
      true
      Expand/Collapse All: 
      
        
          
            False
            Expand All
          
          
            True
            Collapse All