# SSRS Boolean parameter - how can I change True/False label to Male/Female(Radio Button)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

How can i change True/False label to Male/Female? 
I provide values in the available values setting, however it displays the parameters as a drop down. I want to display them as a as Radio button.

Comment: as far as I know you can't do this.

Comment: Please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308928/radio-buttons-in-ssrs-report